# upstairs bathroom plumbing after non use for 10 years

Tags: bathroom, water, water-pressure

upstairs bathroom had a leak from tub over 10 years ago  bathroom was shutdown and basement bathroom was used in mean time. i was gone from house for 3 years during that time ex gutted bathroom. took out toilet and sink. drywall is gone. now ready to re install bathroom and replace tub, tried turning on water at tub(trying to figure original leak) and no water flow. ex does not recall turning anything off except the valves to each individual pipe(toilet, sink and tub).if i have to call plumber i would like to know first what could be issue and possible solutions.

Comment: You need to add photos showing everything, to the question. There just isn't enough to let someone suggest what issues you may have.

Comment: Would check for other shutoff valves first.  No flow should only mean no water or a blockage, time usually does not matter.  Open the other valves and see if water comes out.

Comment: Did you turn on the water supply to your house?